# How can i fix this google translate command error? (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a google translate command but it keeps giving me errors and I can't figure anything out.

This is my code and imports

```
from googletrans import Translator

@bot.command()
async def translate(ctx, lang, *, thing):
    translator = Translator()
    translation = translator.translate(thing, dest=lang)
    await ctx.send(translation.text)
```

Error:

```
Ignoring exception in command translate:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/SeveralForcefulProgrammingtool/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 23, in translate
    translation = translator.translate(thing, dest=lang)
  File "/home/runner/SeveralForcefulProgrammingtool/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googletrans/client.py", line 172, in translate
    raise ValueError('invalid destination language')
ValueError: invalid destination language

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/SeveralForcefulProgrammingtool/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/SeveralForcefulProgrammingtool/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/SeveralForcefulProgrammingtool/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ValueError: invalid destination language
```

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. The destination language is invalid. You need to pass valid languages into that argument. You would need to check the docs for what is valid, but I believe `en-US` should be valid.

Comment: It wasn't that, it was the version of the module. It was buggy that's why it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

```
from googletrans import Translator

def translate_into_english(self, string):
    translater = Translator()
    out = translater.translate(string, dest='en')
    return out.text
```